# Dump Docker Container Memory

Tags: docker, security, kubernetes

I'm working on in memory encryption of dockerized workloads.  Anyways, step 1 is to dump the memory of a simple container with zero protection.  I'm happy dumping that memory either from a host node or from inside a terminal in the container itself.

I've seen a lot of samples, but none of them concretely work.  See this repo: https://github.com/drcrook1/confidential_k8s_test

IDEALLY: I can dump the memory and read the value from the run.py file "my_array" and find its value and also be able to see the env variable: "SECRET_ONE"'s value as well.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: A container doesn't have memory _per se_; it runs a process and then that process uses normal Linux virtual-memory mechanisms.  On native Linux you should be able to see the container process from the host, and if you have a sufficiently privileged process you can probably get at its memory.  Can you find the process's host process ID and from there mmap() a file out of `/proc/<pid>`?

Comment: Yup, I can do this.  Just struggling right now with the PID of the container.  The one being outputted doesn't seem to exist in my currently executing processes.  pid=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' "${containerid}")

Comment: so I'm now able to locate the process and attach to it.  I can cat /proc/PID/maps successfully, but not a lot useful, not sure how to use that data yet.

I also use some random gdb I found on stack overflow that dumps some stuff I'm also not sure what to do with yet.

Comment: You can dump memory of a process with gcore: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html

Comment: @juraj that actually gave me better what I wanted in an easier to post process way and stopped the process for a very minimal amount of time.